# Displaying data from 3 arrays with correct format

Tags: php

Hello and thanks in advance to anyone that can answer my question. I'm still a bit green in terms of PHP but I will try to explain what I want and what my problem is.

I have 3 arrays with MySQL query's results:

- $resultsTextPageID (with pageID value [int(10)])
- $resultsTextPageName (with pageName value [text])
- $resultsTextIntro (with pageIntro value [text])

I would like the final output to be

```
<b><a href="page.php?id=[pageID goes here]">[pageName goes here]</a></b><br />
[pageIntro goes here]<br /><br />
```

Like this:

**[pageName]**
    [pageIntro]
**[pageName]**
    [pageIntro]

I tried the following code:

```
//ECHO PAGEID PART
while ($pageID = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsTextPageID))
{
    echo '<b><a href="page.php?id='.$pageID['pageID'].'">';
    //ECHO PAGENAME PART
    while ($pageName = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsTextPageName))
    {
        echo $pageName['pageName'].'</a></b><br />';
        //ECHO PAGEINTRO PART
        while ($intro = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsTextIntro))
        {
            echo $intro['pageIntro'].'<br /><br />';
        }
    }
}
```

But the output I get is:

**[pageName]**
    [pageIntro]
    [pageIntro]
**[pageName]**

I think the problem is on the way I structured the while loops, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to fix it.

Can someone help me? Again, thanks in advance! :D

EDIT 1:
Here is the query code:

```
//Prepare and set search query string
$q = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 !?.:]+/", " ", $_GET['q']);
//RETRIEVE KEYWORDS
//seperate multiple keywords into array
$keywords = explode(" ", $q);
//Clean empty arrays so they don’t get every row as result
$keywords = array_diff($keywords, array(""));
//MySQL QUERY
$searchTextPageID = "SELECT pageID FROM pages WHERE pageIntro LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%' OR pageText LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'";
$searchTextPageName = "SELECT pageName FROM pages WHERE pageIntro LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%' OR pageText LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'";
$searchTextIntro = "SELECT pageIntro FROM pages WHERE pageIntro LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%' OR pageText LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'";
```

Comment: Why don't you get your data using join in single query?

Comment: Could you please post the query code? I think there's probably an easier way to do the whole thing.

Comment: inner while loop will append `pageIntro` till associative array is empty. Then middle loop will append `pageName`s and then outer loop will append links. Code is working as is written but the logic behind is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Essentilally you should be collecting all 3 pieces of info at one time, if these are all in the same table, the job is quite easy.

```
$qry = "select pageID, pageName, pageIntro from <your table name>";

// now loop thru results
while ($page = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
{
echo '<b><a href="page.php?id='.$page['pageID'].'">';
echo $page['pageName'].'</a></b><p>';
echo $page['pageIntro'].'<br /></p>';

}
```

If the data is spread over more than one table you will have to do a JOIN in your sql.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn´t make much sense since you iterate over every entry of `$resultsTextPageID` but already in the first entry you iterate over all `$resultsTextPageName`. Therefore the second time you enter the body of resultsTextPageID-loop there is no more to fetch from `$resultsTextPageName`. This happens the exact same way to the second/third while-loop.

Assuming you have only one title and only one page intro you can change your code to

```
while ($pageID = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsTextPageID))
{
  /* get only ONE entry */
  $pageName = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsTextPageName);
  $intro = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsTextIntro);

  echo '<b><a href="page.php?id='.$pageID['pageID'].'">';
  echo $pageName['pageName'].'</a></b><br />';
  echo $intro['pageIntro'].'<br /><br />';
}
```

But that is in no way nice code.
You should take a look at mysql JOIN commands to arrange your data correctly in the database select. Then your output code would be much easier.

**EDIT** because you added mysql-code:
you are selecting 3 times from the same db under the same condition, only to retrieve different columns, change it to

```
$searchTextPageID = "SELECT pageIDm, pageName, pageIntro FROM pages WHERE pageIntro LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%' OR pageText LIKE '%".$keywords[$i]."%'";
```